# ADB (Android Debugging): Device unauthorized, Locked out of device with no access to Recovery Mode

Tags: android, windows, debugging, adb, oneplusone

**Background:** 
I have a One Plus 6, I recently made a switch from it to iPhone, but I kept it for all my android needs. It has a PIN, which I used to change frequently enough for security reasons. Now, I've forgotten the combination. I've already given around 50 attempts of what it can be but failed. So unlocking it normally is out of the way.

I only want access to the data now, then I can just get it formatted. The official and local stores have raised their hands, that they can't help me with data extraction and hence I decided to turn to the good old ADB.

**Information about the device:**

1. Power Button and Volume buttons don't work at all.
2. The device has my fingerprint, but since it was restarted it wants the PIN at least once.
3. I'm locked out, as I've entered my PIN wrong multiple times.

**What I've tried:** 
I gave it two attempts:

1. On my Friend's Laptop: I connected it to his laptop. It connects as an ADB device but shows unauthorized. Since It's connecting for the first time I believe I'll need to "Allow" on my Android but that's not possible as I'm locked out.
2. On my own laptop: I've connected my phone earlier too on this laptop, but when I connect it now it doesn't show up in the devices. I'm using the same version of platform-tools on both laptops, so that shouldn't be the issue. My guess is last time I must have connected it as a media transfer device and hence it doesn't connect as an ADB device by default and again I cannit change it.

**What I need help with:** 
I believe I can get that device on the same WiFi Network as my Laptop. But again I won't be able to manually start an FTP server on my phone. Is there anything I can do? Like somehow establish the ADB connection, or authorize it, or enter recovery mode?

Comment: One Plus 6 was released with Android 8.1, so it is encrypted by default. Unless you enter the correct pin, the encryption is active and thus reading the data is impossible. Off-device is impossible because the encryption key is stored in the secured environment that belongs to the Android Gatekeeper system.

Comment: @Robert If I enter the recovery mode, and connect to ADB on my laptop, then too I won't be able to delete/change the lock?

Comment: In recovery mode of a stock device there is some times adb available but this adb is restricted to `adb sideload` thus you can only install a new official firmware. Also removing the lock screen would not remove the encryption, thus even if you could remove the lock screen PIN that way you could still not access the data as these remain encrypted without the correct PIN.